CTF - printf vuln - GOT - can't make it work. GOT @ 0x00404000
I have issues getting my %n exploit in printf vulnerability to work. Any hits ?
Basically, the code calls printf(buf); _exit(0);
I can find _exit with objdump -R
0000000000404018 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT  _exit@GLIBC_2.2.5
I can find my "winner" func with objdump -t - it is @ 0x401320
If I input %1$p%6$sto the buf, it prints something like: 0x7f07e2ecab23%1$p%6$s - Thus I know parameter 6 on the stack is the buffer aka user controllable memory area.
I wrote a small program to calucate things for me, and I get this python that should give me the exploit:
python -c 'print("\x1a\x40\x40\x00\x18\x40\x40\x00%56x%6$hn%4832x%7$hn")'
Can anybody see any mistakes in this ?
I have the higher address first,  due to it receiving the lowest value (0x0040....), and the lower address (aka 0x404018) last as it receives the higher values (0x1320).  I think this is all good.
But the result is, that I am NOT getting any changes written to the GOT.
I tried with the value in here in my printf generating script, it generated same output as here:
https://axcheron.github.io/exploit-101-format-strings/
I have run GDB on the code, seems like my got.plt addresses are unchanged after printf returns.
If I replace \x00 with \x88 or \xAA (to force printf to not terminate early - in my input, the executable fails with segfault)
I can see get more or less the expected number of characters back - 4897 characters - on a segfault.
I am now thinking, passing \x00 in the buffer to printf - I assume that this would cause printf to stop parsing the rest.
Thus, how would I include a 0x00 in the address ? Say write to GOT starting at 0x00404000 ?
I think any address with a 0 byte will be a problem ? I have not found any examples with a 00 in the address to write.
Made my own simple code, same exploit, but due to the location of GOT (0x004040000) I can't make that work either. I am pretty sure the '\0' in the printf strings are terminating the string.
In GHidra it seems like everything is in 0x0040.... addresses.

I tried travelling the stack to a depth of 400 pointers, and did not find a single pointer that was equal to my return address - Thus over-writing that is no option.
